# Vagrant: boot2docker: Unable to find image 'drupal' locally

Tags: drupal, docker, vagrant, boot2docker

I try to run Drupal as a Docker container in the Vagrant box boot2docker (on Windows 8.1).

**Vagrantfile** (Drupal container)

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.provider "docker" do |docker|
    docker.vagrant_vagrantfile = "host/Vagrantfile"
    docker.image = "drupal"
    docker.ports = ['80:80']
    docker.name = 'drupal-container'
  end
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "smb", disabled: true
end
```

**host/Vagrantfile** (boot2docker)

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "mitchellh/boot2docker"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.provision "docker"
  config.vm.hostname = "docker-host"
end
```

Running `vagrant up` in the directory of my Drupal container results in an error, because 'drupal' image can not be found.

**Output**

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'docker' provider...
==> default: Docker host is required. One will be created if necessary...
    default: Vagrant will now create or start a local VM to act as the Docker
    default: host. You'll see the output of the `vagrant up` for this VM below.
    default:
    default: Importing base box 'mitchellh/boot2docker'...
    default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
    default: Checking if box 'mitchellh/boot2docker' is up to date...
    default: Setting the name of the VM: boot2docker_default_1463038875167_93224
    default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
    default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 2375 (guest) => 2375 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 80 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
    default: Booting VM...
    default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: docker
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
    default: Machine booted and ready!
No installation found.
The guest's platform ("tinycore") is currently not supported, will try generic Linux method...
Copy iso file C:\Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the box /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
Installing Virtualbox Guest Additions 5.0.20 - guest version is unknown
mkdir: can't create directory '/tmp/selfgz80627365': No such file or directory
Cannot create target directory /tmp/selfgz80627365
You should try option --target OtherDirectory
An error occurred during installation of VirtualBox Guest Additions 5.0.20. Some functionality may not work as intended.
In most cases it is OK that the "Window System drivers" installation failed.
    default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: No guest additions were detected on the base box for this VM! Guest
    default: additions are required for forwarded ports, shared folders, host only
    default: networking, and more. If SSH fails on this machine, please install
    default: the guest additions and repackage the box to continue.
    default:
    default: This is not an error message; everything may continue to work properly,
    default: in which case you may ignore this message.
    default: Setting hostname...
    default: Running provisioner: docker...
==> default: Warning: When using a remote Docker host, forwarded ports will NOT be
==> default: immediately available on your machine. They will still be forwarded on
==> default: the remote machine, however, so if you have a way to access the remote
==> default: machine, then you should be able to access those ports there. This is
==> default: not an error, it is only an informational message.
==> default: Creating the container...
    default:   Name: drupal-container
    default:  Image: drupal
    default:   Port: 80:80
A Docker command executed by Vagrant didn't complete successfully!
The command run along with the output from the command is shown
below.

Command: "docker" "run" "--name" "drupal-container" "-d" "-p" "80:80" "drupal"

Stderr: Unable to find image 'drupal' locally
Pulling repository drupal
2016/05/12 07:42:05 Could not reach any registry endpoint

Stdout:
```

It works, if I change the box of the host to `ubuntu/trusty64`

**host/Vagrantfile** (ubuntu/trusty64)

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.provision "docker"
  config.vm.hostname = "docker-host"
end
```

but I like to use boot2docker, because it is more lightweight.

What is wrong with my vagrant configuration? How can I get the boot2docker box to work as host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't actually get your configuration to work but I have tested the `mitchellh/boot2docker` box and found the issue. The output of `docker version` inside that box is:

```
Client version: 1.2.0
Client API version: 1.14
Go version (client): go1.3.1
Git commit (client): fa7b24f
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.2.0
Server API version: 1.14
Go version (server): go1.3.1
Git commit (server): fa7b24f
```

This version of docker is very outdated and now unable to pull images from docker hub at all. You can see where the docker team announced the deprecation here: https://blog.docker.com/2015/10/docker-hub-deprecation-1-5/

Currently you must have docker >= 1.6 to pull images from docker hub.

Comment: to add on this - in the second case you're just installing docker on your ubuntu VM not pulling any images

Comment: I assumed they were still using the drupal Vagrantfile from the top of the post also. Although I couldn't get the double-vagrantfile setup to work for me.

Comment: you can't go with docker provider and provision at the same time - either you use docker provision on the system you define (ubuntu/centos ...) that will install docker on this VM and pull images etc ... or you use docker provider which will boost docker on the boot2docker VM (not sure if vagrant has plan for support the native docker now it has been announced for mac/windows)

Comment: What box would you recommend instead?

Comment: I use `hashicorp/boot2docker` now.

Comment: you can remove the `docker.vagrant_vagrantfile` as this is the default box to be used - you set this if you specifically want to use another one.